# ACR120U Reader in BackTrack 5 R3

Tags: linux, nfc, mifare

I am unable to use ACR120U reader in BackTrack 5 R3 (Linux),I have already downloaded the necessary [drivers](http://www.acs.com.hk/drivers/eng/ACR120U_driver_Lnx_1504_A.zip) and installed them.

`lsusb` shows ACR reader as connected, but how to use it,
`nfc-list` shows no RFID readers.

Comment: I don't think libnfc [supports](http://www.libnfc.org/documentation/hardware/compatibility) the ACR120U. Ask on their [forum](http://www.libnfc.org/community).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libnfc`do not supports `ACR120U reader`.
I had to use `ACR122 reader` to get things done.